# is htaccess is need to placed in every sub folder

Tags: .htaccess

i am using the .htaccess for the first time and as every where shows i tried the following code to get the clean url

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^address/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ detail.php?add=$1

i also tried to modify it to

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^address/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ detail.php?add=$1
```

But it is not working. is it because i have placed in the main directory and the detail.php is in a folder "content"?

Comment: That file shold be in the root directory (example: `public_html`) but if you place a `.htaccess` in a subfolder of root, that file will be accepted as well. About the code, someone with better understanding may help you.

Comment: Thank u for ur reply and hope so